# Find 36 connected lowest values in a column and return it as a DF

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

everyone,

i'm currently trying to find and return the 36 smallest contiguous values from a column with cycle times using pandas/python. 
I can do this with the use of loops. With the loops I go through line by line (36 lines together) and check what the smallest sum is. 
With a data set of more than 1,000,000 rows this takes time, of course.

I look for a solution/function within pandas that finds these 36 connected (consecutive) smallest rows and returns them to me as an DataFrame.

Is there somebody who can help me?

BR
Steffen

Comment: Hi Steffen, please familiarise yourself with [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you write your next question! Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Comment: How about `df["some_row"].rolling(36).sum().min()`?